# Best approach to migrate taxonomy and tagging from SPO to another SPO

Tags: taxonomy, content-migration, document-migration, spo

What is best way to migrate taxonomy and tagging from SPO site to another SPO?

I have find Share gate tool for that, but i am not sure so can any body suggest if any other tools or manual migration for the same?

Answer (score 1):

The "best practice" (and probably also the easiest approach nowadays) would be using PnP Provisioning in one of its flavours:

[https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP](http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/01/14/export-and-import-site-collection-term-groups-using-pnp-powershell/)
[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps][2]

http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/01/14/export-and-import-site-collection-term-groups-using-pnp-powershell/

Export-PnPTaxonomy
Import-PnPTaxonomy

(I did this in the past using PnP PowerShell, at that point in time the engine was clumbersome when dealing with taxonomies and I had to tweek it a bit, but later the issues were resolved, good luck! (no pun intented)

J

Comment: Thanks Jaime, This works fine if i want to just import terms from another site but if i want to migrate document library along with meta data column then can you suggest?

Comment: Mmmm I don't remember having problems with that, we had managed metadata columns on libraries and they were exported just fine. Once you are connected to the tenant try to get the XML template of the site using the Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.xml cmd, (this will retrieve all Delta changes to an OOTB site ), I would inspect the XML, you should see a section with Lists and an instance of the doc lib with the custom metadata columns there.